# How to run script behind alert box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to run `alert("hi")` in 3 seconds after `alert("hello")` without clicking on OK of "hello" alert.

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
    alert("hello");
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("hi");
    },3000)
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the [**doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) you will understand that is not possible:

> **Notes**
>
> The alert dialog **should be used for messages which do not require any
>   response on the part of the user**, other than the acknowledgement of
>   the message.
>
> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).
>
> Chrome users (e.g. extensions) should use methods of nsIPromptService
>   instead.

Answer (score 4):

When `alert` alerts, it blocks the UI as well as the thread. do that. The next line of code runs after the `alert` has been dismissed.

So, there's no way to do that. You can use Twitter's Bootstrap's modals, may be. (There are many others too, like Foundation, jQuery UI that gives you the ability to have a modals)

Comment: Plus one for the suggestion for non-built in modals. The only solution really.